# How to style elements for an element within a div tag?

Tags: html, css

I know this is a question from someone that is new in the comunity, however I couldn't find the right answer anywhere.
My html snippet looks like this:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <!--Create an unordered list in order to get the title bar of the site -->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The idea is that I want to style the unordered list.

My css code looks something like this:

```
#navigation li {
    display: inline; 
}
```

Clearly this doesn't work, however I was hoping someone could guide me in the right direction of how to actually pin point an element within a div tag?

Edit: Well, sorry everyone I forgot to reference my css page in my HTML code... good grief!

Comment: Why are you saying that it doesn't work? Have you inspected the element styles using your browser's development tools? It's not because your CSS rules aren't producing the correct result that they aren't getting applied to the elements.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="navigation">
    <!--Create an unordered list in order to get the title bar of the site -->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Category3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Category4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#navigation li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #3e3e3e;
}
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/68Pe8/)

Answer (score 2):

This CSS code will, in fact, work. Your code now will apply to all `li` tags inside of divider(s) with the `id` of `navigation`.

Most likely, the reason you do not think it is working is because `inline` is the default value for the `display` property. Therefore, you are likely not changing any formatting or style of the `<li>` tags. Is there a specific style you are trying to apply to the `<li>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

The text and code does nothing for me to understand your question ...but I assume you are just learning to style and code....My suggestion is try adding it on fiddle like this:

```
#navigation {overflow: hidden; margin: 1em; border: 1px solid #ff0000;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/58u6P/

Answer (score 0):

This style is perfectly fine and does work.  Are you asking how to further style your li's?

If so, you may want to take a look at the following resource on how to select exactly the tag you want to style with CSS:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

Comment: @Shivian Raptor, well played, updated with a more complete link.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the right thing. What you have should be working fine.
There are a few ways to select that list...

select the `<ul>`

```
ul{}
div ul{}
#navigation ul{}
div#navigation ul{}
```

select the `<li>`s

```
li{}
div li{}
div ul li{}
div#navigation li{}
div#navigation ul li{}
#navigation li{}
#navigation ul li{}
#navigation ul li:nth-child(3){}
```

The more specific selector will override less specific ones. This can be seen here - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/psjgD 
A list of specific selectors can be [found here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
#navigation li{ display: inline-block;}
```

I think this is what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkasarora/bvLAU/3/) I have created. This will guide you in right direction. :)

To pin point the elements simply do like you are doing now, For example,

```
#navigation ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#navigation li {
  float:left;
  border-left:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `float: left` for auto layout arrangement.

```
#navigation li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
#navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G27Sm/)